# JSF Forward and redirect

Tags: jsf, icefaces

Currently i am working on a JSF ([ICEfaces](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEfaces/)
) project. I am having a menu where the menu data comes from the database. I mean label and url comes from the database. I am executing the query and writing a logic for the menu. Up to that JSF is good.

Suppose i clicked on a link of menu. I got a page. In that page I am having 3 buttons. Add, Update & Delete buttons. For the add navigation i used

```
<ice:outputLink/>
```

For the remaining i used

```
<ice:commandLink/>
```

I can navigate from one page to another page with the above. Problem i am getting is when returning to the previous page, page is not going. After googling what i noticed is page navigation is by default forwards.

When navigation is forward, why the previous page is not coming....

Please help,

Thanks vipul

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet of the error you are getting when going to previous page?

Comment: I am not getting any kind of error..For redirect it works properly..Without redirect previous page is not coming..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally understanding your problem, but i'm thinking that what you may be looking for is the have the url change in the browser when you click a link.

To do that, just add "`?faces-redirect=true`" to your link.

example:

```
<ice:outputLink value="mylink?faces-redirect=true" />
```

A side note, why do you want to use Icefaces when it is a complete rip off of primefaces? Why not just use the original code (primefaces)? See this link for explanation - http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1692.